# Is Waterlock production-ready?

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js, jwt

I'm new to Sails.js and stumbled across JWT module called [Waterlock](http://waterlock.ninja/). At a glance, it has local and social authentication which are what I'm looking for, which is nice.

However I wonder if this module is production-ready. [The last update in Github was long ago](https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock/graphs/contributors) and being unmaintained.

If it isn't, is there any production-ready JWT module which does similar to Waterlock available for Sails.js?

Answer (score -1):

Go with Passport.js, Which is stable and if you stuck anywhere there is large community.

[Authentication and Permissioning with Sails + Passport](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies/sails-passport)

[Implement Passport.js authentication with Sails.js](http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/)

Comment: I believe with Passport, it doesn't handle JWT authentication for you. Am I correct?